# Sum of consecutive numbers where a certain multiple is removed

Tags: arithmetic

I tried to generate a certain rule and observe for a pattern, the rule goes like this:
$$f( \textbf {3}) = 1 + 2 = 3 (1^{2})$$
$$f(6) = f( \textbf{3}*2) = 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 = 12 = 3(2^{2})$$
$$f(9) = f( \textbf{3}*3) = 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 7 + 8 = 27 = 3(3^{2})$$

This pattern goes for every number I observed like
$$f(2) = f( \textbf{2}) = 1  = 1(1^{2})$$
$$f(4) = f( \textbf{2}*2) = 1 + 3 = 4 = 1(2^{2})$$
$$f(6) = f( \textbf{2}*3) = 1 + 3 + 5 = 9 = 1(3^{2})$$

or this
$$f(4) = f( \textbf{4}) = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 = 6(1^{2})$$
$$f(8) = f( \textbf{4}*2) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 24 = 6(2^{2})$$
$$f(12) = f( \textbf{4}*3) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 9 + 10 + 11 = 54 = 6(3^{2})$$

It can be noticed that all of them can be expressed in the form $an^2$ where $\textbf{a}$ is the result of the mother sequence while $\textbf {n}$ runs from 1 onwards.

It seems obvious but I couldn't crack the explanation why this happens.

I tried it to express as a sum, like this:
$$f(12) = f( \textbf{4}*3) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 9 + 10 + 11 = 54 = 6(3^{2})$$
$$f(12) = f( \textbf{4}*3) = (1 + 2 + 3) + (5 + 6 + 7) + (9 + 10 + 11)$$
$$f(12) = f( \textbf{4}*3) = (1 + 2 + 3) + 3(1 + 2 + 3) + 5(1 + 2 + 3)$$
but I do not know where to go after this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a different $f$ for each block of patterns? At any rate, it appears that the rule you are using is a linear combination of two triangular numbers. Determine which two, and then use the formula $T_n = n(n+1)/2$ to derive your rule.

Comment: Your $f$ changes between paragraphs.  In the first $f(6)=12$ while in the second $f(6)=9$  You should use different letters or probably a second argument.  You should also describe in words how you choose which numbers to sum instead of forcing people to figure out the pattern.  I would suggest $f(a,b)$ is the sum of the numbers $1$ through $ab$ deleting all the multiples of $a$.  That shows you have the difference of two triangular numbers $f(a,b)=T_{ab}-aT_b$ and can use the formula for triangular numbers to derive what you are seeing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let  $ f(a) = 1+2+3 .... (a-1) = \frac {(a-1)*(a)}{2} $

now we let $ f(a) = \frac {(a-1)*(a)}{2} = A $

and we look at $ f(a*b)=f(a) + ( a+1 + a+2...+ 2a-1) + ...(a(b-1)+1 ... a(b)-1) $

now we notice $ f(a*b)= f(a) + (f(2a)-f(a)-a) + (f(3a)-f(2a)-2a) .... (f(ab)-f(a(b-1)))         -a(b-1)  $

$ f(a*b)= f(ab)- a-2a-3a ..... -(b-1)a = f(ab) - a\frac{(b-1)(b)}{2} $

from above we have $ f(ak) =  \frac {(ak-1)(ak)}{2} = a[ \frac {(ak-1)(k)}{2} ] $

and  $ a[ \frac {(ak-1)(k)}{2} ] = A * \frac {(ak-1)(k)}{(a-1)} = f(ak) $

finally we have

$ f(a*b)= f(ab) - a\frac{(b-1)(b)}{2} $ =$ A \frac {(ab-1)(b)}{(a-1)} - \frac{(a)(a-1)}{2}[ \frac {(b-1)*(b)}{a-1}] $

$ f(a*b) = A [\frac {(ab-1)(b)}{(a-1)} - \frac {(b-1)(b)}{a-1} ]$

last step :

$ [\frac {(ab-1)(b)}{(a-1)} - \frac {(b-1)(b)}{a-1} ]= \frac {abb-b-bb+b}{a-1} = \frac {(a-1)bb}{a-1} = \frac {bb}{1}$

and we get $ f(a*b) = A bb = A(b)^{2} = f(a)(b)^{2} $

Comment: notice that I didn't mention f(ab) is as ab=n where n is a number and not as an operation a*b .

Comment: Thank you...your solution is elegant. I didn't realize that a simple pattern like that need a complex proof like this. Thanks. As of now I am trying to comprehend your work...May I ask, how did you get f(2a)..f(3a) and f(ab)?

Comment: I understand it all. Thank you very much!

Comment: if you look at the sum of the group (1,2,3...n-1) its obvious its f(n), then the sum of the two groups (n+1,n+2....2n-1) it would be f(2n) if it was (1,2,3....... ,2n-1) here we noticethat f(2n) -f(n) = sum of (n,n+1....2n-1) which is the same group (n+1,n+2...,2n-1) +a , and that holds for ever other groups from (1,2,....,n-1) (n+1,n+2........,2n-1) (2n+1,...3n-1) ....=f(n*b)

Comment: how did you get a*(b-1) in f(a*b) = f(a) + (a+1) + (a+2) + . . . + a*(b-1)? Every time I substitute values it didn't agree but I believe that it's correct since it end up very well. Would you please explain a*(b-1)? thanks!